# which error is correct

Tags: apex

```
try{
    List<String> nameList;
    Account a;
    String s = a.Name;
    nameList.add(s);
}
    catch(ListException le)
        {
        System.debug('List Exception');
        }
    catch( NullpointerException npe )
        {
        System.debug('Nullpointer Exception');
        }
    catch( Exception e )
        {
        System.debug ('Generic Exception') ;
        }
}
```

I couldn't figure out the correct answer, list is not initialised so according to me null pointer exception should come but I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer :** It will be **Nullpointer Exception**.

**Why** : both the list and the account variable are null (since they are not initialised to a value), based on the sequence of statements, when `a.Name` gets executed, it will throw the **Nullpointer Exception** since you are trying to retrieve a property value out of null

**Proof** :
You can simply execute the same code in your developer console execute anonymous and check the log
[image]